# PHP: How to Create Object Variables?

Tags: php, class, variables, object, automation

So for example I have this code:

```
class Object{
    public $tedi;
    public $bear;
    ...some other code ...
}
```

Now as you can see there are public variables inside this class. What I would like to do is to make these variables in a dynamic way, with a function something like:

```
private function create_object_vars(){

   // The Array what contains the variables
   $vars = array("tedi", "bear");

   foreach($vars as $var){
      // Push the variables to the Object as Public
      public $this->$var;
   }
}
```

So how should I create public variables in a dynamic way?

Comment: Sorry @Pekka , I though it's clear but I attached it to the end :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

You're pretty much correct - this should do it:

```
private function create_object_vars(){

   // The Array of names of variables we want to create
   $vars = array("tedi", "bear");

   foreach($vars as $var){
      // Push the variables to the Object as Public
      $this->$var = "value to store";
   }
}
```

Note that this makes use of [variable variable naming](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which can do some crazy and dangerous things!

As per the comments, members created like this will be public - I'm sure there's a way of creating protected/private variables, but it's probably not simple (eg you could do it via the C Zend API in an extension).

Comment: but in your snippet, there is no public , will it be public as default?

Comment: @CIRK - yes member variables created in this way will be public by default (in PHP 4 all members were public) - I'm not sure if there's a simple way of creating non-public variables.

Comment: and what about the variable variables? what do you mean under this?

Comment: Well if you don't assign anything it wouldn't be a valid PHP statement.  You could assign `null` if you want to create the variable but leave it empty.

Comment: Yes, in `$this->$var`, `$var` is a variable variable, since it's using the *value* of `$var` for the variable name.  Note that you can use this with similarly with local variables as `$$var`.

Comment: But in general I'd try and avoid using variable variables unless you've got a good reason.

Answer (score 49):

```
$vars = (object)array("tedi"=>"bear");
```

or

```
$vars = new StdClass();
$vars->tedi = "bear";
```

Comment: @bfg9k please lend me a helping hand on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295574/how-to-convert-8209-array-object-variant-to-vt-variant

Answer (score 6):

As alternative, you can also derive your object from `ArrayObject`. So it inherits array-behaviour and a few methods which make injecting attributes easier.

```
class YourObject extends ArrayObject {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(array(), ArrayObject::PROPS_AS_ARRAY);
    }

    function create_object_vars() {
        foreach ($vars as $var) {

            $this[$var] = "some value";

        }
    }
```

Attributes will then be available as `$this->var` and `$this["var"]` likewise, which may or not may suit the use case. The alternative method for setting attributes would be `$this->offsetSet("VAR", "some value");`.

Btw, there is nothing evil about variable variables. They're a proper language construct, as would be reusing ArrayObject.